# Angular shows fake status code: Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: (HTTP status: -1 )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Recently, in development, I am seeing angular fail to find templates that are there, and the status code that it gives me is not a real status code.

Template files in my Angular app fail to render, and the browser seems to try again (server logs go berserk) until it settles and it looks just fine. I can't consistently reproduce the issue, and I can't seem to find any similar errors on SO etc with an HTTP status code of `-1`.

Console error:

`Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: /assets/some_folder/template_file.html (HTTP status: -1 )`

I am using Angular 1.5.7 through the Rails 4.1 asset pipeline if that helps. Browser is Chrome 56  on Ubuntu 16.04.